# How to invoke a grid when particular node of treeview is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

I have a treeview created by using html helper as shown below

```
@(Html.Kendo().TreeView()
        .Name("treeview-left")
        .DataTextField("Domains")
        .Items(treeview =>
        {
            treeview.Add().Text("SystemModelling");

            treeview.Add().Text("SystemConfiguration")
                .Items(furniture =>
                {
                    furniture.Add().Text("Root");

                });
            treeview.Add().Text("Domains");
            treeview.Add().Text("Roles");
            treeview.Add().Text("Users");
        })
        .Events(ev=>ev.Select("treview_select"))
    )
```

i created a kendo grid in partial view , i have to trigger that  grid only if i click "Domains" node how to achieve it in `treview_select` event?

**EDIT**

created everything but now grid is throwing for all nodes, how to make it specific to Domains node

**EDIT**

How to trigger .Events for a particular node say "Domains" here rather than for all node for grid?

**EDIT**

I did coding like `var node = e.node;` in the `treview_select` event  of java script but not able to catch it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i figured out ,so the code i did in javascript is shown below `this.text(e.node)` will do the trick

```
 if (this.text(e.node) == "Domains") {
                $.ajax({
                    url: $("#GridURL").val(),
                    type: "POST",
                    success: function (result) {
                        $("#gridcontiner").html(result);
                    }
                });
            }
```